# How reset Form with button type reset work with field is loaded by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to implement a reset button to reset form.

When click button reset, it will reset all data to data saved in database.

It works perfectly for almost all fields, but I have some fields which are loading data by JavaScript (data is filled by js).

And this point reset button reset all this fields to empty

Is there a way to fix it in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(':input','#myForm').not('.ignoreFieldClassName');
```

Comment: your solution works the way not execute reset in specific fields, it isn't my expectation. i want reset specific is loaded by JS to data in database, not reset to empty